# remove n before a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data-extraction

I want to remove unrequired r and n at beginning of each upper-case word and number in this string. I tried regex. Not sure if regex or some other method would be helpful here.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
text = "nFamily n49 new nTom"

regex_pattern =  re.compile(r'.*n[A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]*\s')
matches = regex_pattern.findall(text)
for match in matches:
    text = text.replace(match," ")
print(text)
```

Expected output:

```
Family 49 new Tom
```

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'\b[rn](?=[A-Z\d])', "", text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
text = re.sub(r'\bn(?=[A-Z0-9])', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u26rp2/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - here, start of a word
- `n` - a `n` letter
- `(?=[A-Z0-9])` - a positive lookahead that requires an uppercase ASCII letter or a digit to be present immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vCWBmO):

```py
import re
rx = r"\bn(?=[A-Z0-9])"
text = "nFamily n49 new nTom"
print( re.sub(rx, '', text) )
# => Family 49 new Tom
```